# imagemagick - reduce image quality lower than 1%?

Tags: imagemagick

How can I reduce the image quality lower than 1%? For example, 0.5%? My failed attempt:

```
  IFS=$'\n'
  for f in $(find . -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname "*.png")
  do
    convert -quality 0.5% -resize 70% "$f" "${f%.*}-placeholder${f//*./.}"
  done
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you want to reduce the quality of an image, you can reduce the number of pixels. This method combined with the option `-quality` can reduce the overall 'quality' to less than 1%. - Why do you want this?

Comment: @sudodus how can we reduce the number of pixels?

Comment: See this link: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/

Answer (score 1):

For `imagemagick` valid highest compression value is `1%`. Therefore any value less than `1%` (higher compression), like the following

```
convert -quality '0.5%' input.jpg output.jpg
```

will not work<sup>[1](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality)</sup>.

---

<sup>1. https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#quality</sup>